# detectron2 return data did not register, but i registered it?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, detectron

I am currently trying to import the DiffusionDet model, which is based on detectron2, in order to train it on a new dataset. Following the detectron2 readme, I attempted to register the aquarium dataset. However, when I run the train_net.py file, it always returns "dataset "aqua_train" didn't register".

Despite the fact that "aqua_train" appears at the end of the list returned by DatasetCatalog.list(), and DatasetCatalog.get("aqua_train") accurately returns the JSON content in the train folder.

[this is the error returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajSwj.png)

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue? I downloaded this data and JSON file following the COCO format on Roboflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i got the answer. When i register, i register in the command cell in colab. and when run the train_net.py, the system call for the pointer self (from train_net.py and this self didn't register the dataset).

So i just add the register function into train_net.py

Thanks